# how to make fa fa-check as background image for the selected field in Angular 4 using ng-select

Tags: angular, sass, font-awesome

i have a ng-select field, i want to set the check mark for the selected field in the dropdown list, so i wanted to using fontawesome `check`, but i am not getting how to set that, can anyone help me

HTML:

```
 <ng-select class="box"  placeholder="{{selected}}" [options]="company" [(ngModel)]="selected"></ng-select>




SCss:
.box {
    select-dropdown .selected {
    color: #82ffe4 !important;
    background-color: #4389a9 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: MontserratRegular;
 }
}
```

Ts:

```
this.company = [
    { label:"Wiredelta",value: "Wiredelta" },
    { label:"Timer", value: "Timer" },
    { label:"Artifu", value: "Artifu" },
    { label:"BoatButler", value: "BoatButler" },
  ];
    this.selected="Wiredelta";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by giving in scss like this

```
select-dropdown .selected:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c";
    float: right;
    margin-right: -6px;
  }
```